# Proving that the solution to the IVP exists given a condition on the right hand side

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following IVP: 
$x'=f(t,x)$ $\ $and $\ $ $x(0)=x_0$ where $x\in \mathbb{R^n}$ and $t\in \mathbb{R}$.

Suppose that for all $(t,x)\in\mathbb{R^{n+1}}$: $|f(t,x)|\leq b(t) |x|^2$.

In order for the solution to the IVP to exist for all $t>=0$, what conditions should we impose on $b(t)$ and $x_0$?

I know that if the function $f: \mathbb{R^{n+1}}\to \mathbb{R^n}$ is continuous, then there is a theorem (Peano Theorem) that guarantees that the solution to the IVP exists, but I can't seem to find a way to prove the continuity of $f$. I wonder if anyone of you knows another way on how to solve this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If $x_0=0$, then $x(t)=0$ is a solution. Otherwise, I do not see any condition you might impose to guarantee existence. Consider for instance
$$
f(x,t)=\begin{cases}
\phantom{-}x^2 & \text{if $x\in\mathbb{Q}$,}\\
-x^2 & \text{if $x\not\in\mathbb{Q}$.}
\end{cases}
$$
Then $|f(x,t)|\le|x|^2$, with $b(t)=1$.

Comment: Do you mean that the solution to the IVP always exists? Can we impose that $b(t)\geq 0$ or $b(t)$ has to be continuous?. I was also doubting if this has to do with Gronwall's inequality?

Comment: There is a solution if $x_0=0$. In my example, there are no solutions if $x_0\ne0$, even if $b$ is positive and continuous.